# Rank/Rownumber function in SSIS Dataflow

Tags: sql, ssis, rownum

In my dataflow, after some lookups I would get duplicate customer records(They are not exact duplicates only the customer ID is the same), based on some attributes of the customer like city, location. I need to choose one record among them.

How I can achieve this in SSIS dataflow

Here is the sample data:

```
;with cust (CustomerID,Cutomer_Name,score)
as 
(Select 1 as CustomerID, 'abd' as Cutomer_Name, 100 as Score
union 
select 1,'abd',null
union select 1,'abd',20
)  

select * from cust
```

From here I need to choose the record the with lowest score and send only that row to the final table.

It's easy to achieve with Rownum function in SQL, but this case occurs during the dataflow in SSIS

Comment: Could you give some examples on how you decide which record to keep.

Comment: Yep share the logic that you would use to pick the right record in case of duplicate customer ID

Comment: here is the sample data:

Comment: Added the sample data to the main question

Answer (score 2):

Do the source's data access mode on an SQL command.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to acheive this in SSIS dataflow task... Since the rows are duplicated after some lookup's and not at the Source

Comment: above is the OLE DB Source component in the the data flow.

Comment: The data is not duplicate at the source... the duplicates are started after some transformations on the source data ...in the middle of the data flow path.

Comment: Don't create the duplicates. Add more specifics to your question if you want a more intelligent answer.

Comment: I agree with @Metaphor. Fix the logic that is incorrectly creating duplicates. If you want to do something in a script component to learn how it works that's fine but IMHO it's the least efficient and possibly most complex way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a MultiCast to split it into two Outputs - say Output1 and Output2. One of the outputs connect to a Aggregate transformation and Group by CustomerId and do a Minimum of Score. Now connect back the output of the Aggregate transform to Output2 use a Merge Join in the mapping map Output2.CustomerId = Aggregate Transform.Score and Output2.CustomerId = Aggregate Transform.Score. This would do the trick, but if you have multiple customerIds with the same score then you might need a Sort after this step to remove duplicates. Hope this helps.

Comment: Best tip I could find for ranking

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which helped me to solve my issue

http://paultebraak.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/rank-partitioning-in-etl-using-ssis/

Comment: I don't like script tasks for obvious reasons... Hence I would still do it using SSIS tasks.